# CakePHP Twitter plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, twitter

Appologies if this is something obvious I've missed.

I'm trying to use this Cake [plugin](https://github.com/mishudark/CakePHP-2.x-Twitter-Plugin) to add a twitter feed to my cake app (just display my latest tweet). I've followed the docs in the readme but I get this:

```
Missing Controller
Error: Twitter.UsersController could not be found.
Error: Create the class UsersController below in file: C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\Plugin\Twitter\Controller\UsersController.php
```

Heres what I've done so far (as the readme instructs):

1. Cloned all the files into app/Plugin/Twitter/
2. Rename Config/twitter.default.php to Config/twitter.php
3. Updated the config file with my twitter app keys
4. Visited mysite/twitter/twitter/connect - which gives me the above error.

The readme mentions that the plugin uses - http_socket_oauth, another cake plugin, I trust that this is included in this plugin and that I dont have to install that plugin aswel?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: how you authenticate users?  maybe you require authorization for each page by default?

Comment: Good point, I use Auth and ACL - I'll add a allow rule in.

Comment: Nope - even totally doing $this->Auth->allow('*'); across the whole app results in the same error.

Comment: try to turn off Auth and ACL if possible. cause Auth->allow('*') does not supported in last versions of cakephp. Just compare http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-AuthComponent.html#_allow  and http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-AuthComponent.html#_allow

Comment: Did you add `CakePlugin::load('Twitter');` to your bootstrap.php?

Comment: @Costa Yes, the plugin has been loaded via CakePlugin::loadAll();